# Connecting to Access from Excel, then create table from txt file

Tags: vba

I am writing VBA code for an Excel workbook.  I would like to be able to open a connection with an Access database, and then import a txt file (pipe delimited) and create a new table in the database from this txt file.  I have searched everywhere but to no avail.  I have only been able to find VBA code that will accomplish this from within Access itself, rather than from Excel.  Please help!  Thank you

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=create+access+table+from+excel+vba

Comment: Have a look here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16312375/opening-access-from-excel-vba

Answer (score 0):

Google "Open access database from excel VBA" and you'll find lots of resources.  Here's the general idea though:

```
Dim db As Access.Application
Public Sub OpenDB()

Set db = New Access.Application
db.OpenCurrentDatabase "C:\My Documents\db2.mdb"
db.Application.Visible = True

End Sub
```

You can also use a data access technology like ODBC or ADODB.  I'd look into those if you're planning more extensive functionality.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Ageonix, but once the connection has been opened, how would I command Access to import the text file that I desire?

Comment: Just so I'm clear, you want to open/import a text file within Excel, then use that to create a new table in Access?  How are you going to determine the table structure?  Or do you mean the table already exists in Access and you just want to dump the text file data into the table?  I think you're going to need more info than what I text file would give you.

Comment: I would like to be able to execute VBA code in Excel, that will tell Access to open a database, create a new table, and populate that table with the data from a txt file.  The txt file contains data delimited by a character (comma, pipe, semicolon, doesn't matter)

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this exact same problem. You have a large problem presented in a small question here, but here is my solution to the hardest hurdle. You first parse each line of the text file into an array:

```
Function ParseLineEntry(LineEntry As String) As Variant
'Take a text file string and parse it into individual elements in an array.
    Dim NumFields As Integer, LastFieldStart As Integer
    Dim LineFieldArray() As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    'Determine how many delimitations there are. My data always had the format
    'data1|data2|data3|...|dataN|, so there was always at least one field.
    NumFields = 0
    For I = 1 To Len(LineEntry)
        If Mid(LineEntry, i, 1) = "|" Then NumFields = NumFields + 1
    Next i
    ReDim LineFieldArray(1 To NumFields)

    'Parse out each element from the string and assign it into the appropriate array value
    LastFieldStart = 1
    For i = 1 to NumFields
        For j = LastFieldStart To Len(LineEntry)
            If Mid(LineEntry, j , 1) = "|" Then
                LineFieldArray(i) = Mid(LineEntry, LastFieldStart, j - LastFieldStart)
                LastFieldStart = j + 1
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    ParseLineEntry = LineFieldArray
End Function
```

You then use another routine to add the connection in (I am using ADODB). My format for entries was `TableName|Field1Value|Field2Value|...|FieldNValue|`:

```
Dim InsertDataCommand as String

'LineArray = array populated by ParseLineEntry
InsertDataCommand = "INSERT INTO " & LineArray(1) & " VALUES ("
For i = 2 To UBound(LineArray)
    If i = UBound(LineArray) Then
        InsertDataCommand = InsertDataCommand & "'" & LineArray(i) & "'" & ")"
    Else
        InsertDataCommand = InsertDataCommand & LineArray(i) & ", "
    End If
Next i
```

Just keep in mind that you will have to build some case handling into this. For example, if you have an empty value (e.g. `Val1|Val2||Val4`) and it is a string, you can enter "" which will already be in the ParseLineEntry array. However, if you are entering this into a number column it will fail on you, you have to insert `"Null"` instead inside the string. Also, if you are adding any strings with an apostrophe, you will have to change it to a `''`. In sum, I had to go through my lines character by character to find these issues, but the concept is demonstrated.

I built the table programmatically too using the same parsing function, but of this .csv format: `TableName|Field1Name|Field1Type|Field1Size|...|`.

Again, this is a big problem you are tackling, but I hope this answer helps you with the less straight forward parts.