# Can't connect to Access DB, neither with OleDB, DAO, etc

Tags: vba, ms-access, oledb, dao

I want to read and write data from a CATIA macro to and from an Access DataBase. I've got Windows 10 and Office 2013 on it (64bit Windows).

Unfortunately I can't connect to that Access DataBase from VBA. (From VB.NET works fine)

I tried it all:

Various connection strings (JET.4.0, ACE.12.0) etc with ADODB
-> Error that Provider cant be found

Connection via DAO
-> Various other errors

Any idea why I cant connect?

I referenced all DLLs possible to reference, etc.

Only idea I have that theres a problem with Access 2013 32bit and the 64 bit Windows?

Comment: how did you try ? Piece of code ? Can you show it ?

Comment: what about this ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/54269372/78522

Comment: Is Access installed on the client machine ? ADO ?

Comment: Catia bitness x64? Have Office and Catia the same bitness or mess with [Why can't 32 and 64 bit Access Database Engine (ACE/OLEDB Dataproviders) coexist](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=https%3a%2f%2fsocial.msdn.microsoft.com%3a443%2fForums%2fen-US%2fabf34eea-1029-429a-b88e-4671bffcee76%2fwhy-cant-32-and-64-bit-access-database-engine-aceoledb-dataproviders-coexist%3fforum%3dadodotnetdataproviders%26prof%3drequired)

Comment: Please don't ask a question without explaining what you tried and what error you got.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I'll remember them next time I ask a question.

Access is installed (so is Office). I think CATIA is 64bit, which is probably the problem. That means it is impossible to connect to the database?

Answer (score 0):

I tried from Excel with the following code ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54269372/78522)), it works like a charm.

```
Sub test()
    Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection 'Requieres reference to the Microsoft
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset   'ActiveX Data Objects Library

    Set cnn = CreateObject("adodb.Connection")
    cnn.Open "DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\Users\someFolder\myDb.accdb;"
    Set rs = cnn.Execute("SELECT * FROM versions")
    While Not rs.EOF
      Debug.Print rs(1), rs(2), rs(3)
      rs.MoveNext
    Wend
    rs.Close
End Sub
```

if that doesn't work, the client PC may [lack a piece of software](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/168335/info-using-activex-data-objects-ado-via-visual-basic) ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!

Unfortunately I get the following error, further confirming the 32/64bit problem:

[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified